# Can I upload an app to the iOS AppStore using Xcode 9 and macOS Mojave?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store-connect, macos-mojave

Just wondering if this is possible, I’m running MacOS mojave (beta) and using a stable version of Xcode 9. But can I still upload to the AppStore even though I’m using a beta OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Apple doesn't allow upload the apps using beta versions of Xcode, but doesn't restrict to do this using a beta OS. [more details](https://developer.apple.com/support/beta-software/)